# Getting an error converting from varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger, historical-db

I made a historical table along with a trigger function built in the reference table. Is based on possible name changes for an user and as well recording down the date.

My trigger built:

[image]

Target table:

[image]

The trigger function pulls the names off the table.

[image]

But I'm getting error converting data type. All my data that I'm updating are of `VARCHAR` type. Where am I missing?

Comment: First note: `SELECT Col FROM DELETED/INSERTED` without a `WHERE` clause is won't do what are think it do, and it's even not going to do what is expected especially when the deleted rows are > 1. What is the version you are working with?

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER 17.9

Comment: You get this error cause you are trying to insert a varchar into int column, you are trying to insert `@oldlastname` to `patientid`. SQL Server try to cast the string in `@oldlastname` to numeric and fail. Plus you need to avoid using `MAX() + 1` cause this won't work if you delete some rows, and you need to join the tables instead of using those variables.

Comment: What are other options besides using Max+1? I need it to increment the primary key in the historic table.

Comment: @Dan . . . Use an `identity` column -- let the database do the work for you.

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement references `dbo.patientLastNameChange`, but your question says that the target table is `dbo.patientFirstNameChange`.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `INSERT..VALUES` statement to `INSERT..SELECT` and set aliases for all the columns. Make sure the aliases match the every column in the target table (defaulting all `NOT NULL` columns), and *they are in the same order as they are declared*.
Note that the `SELECT` statement uses the `patientLastNameChange` table, because the `MAX()` without a `GROUP BY` ensures only one row is returned.
I recommend to use `COALESCE` to set the `MAX()` result to `0` if it returns `NULL`. Then simply add `1` to increment the `lastNameChangeID`. I think this is more readable.

```
CREATE TRIGGER patientLastNameChangeTrigger
ON patient
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @oldLastName VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT pt_lastName FROM DELETED);
    DECLARE @newLastName VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT pt_lastName FROM INSERTED);

    IF @oldLastName <> @newLastName
        INSERT INTO dbo.patientLastNameChange (lastnameChangeID, patientID, oldLastName, newLastName, datechanged)
        SELECT
        COALESCE(MAX(plnc.lastnameChangeID),0)+1 AS lastnameChangeID,
        (SELECT patientID FROM INSERTED) AS patientID,
        @oldLastName AS oldLastName,
        @newLastName AS newLastName,
        GETDATE() AS datechanged
        FROM patientLastNameChange plnc;
END;
```